# How to locate and display symbols when using /GL?

Tags: visual-studio, dumpbin

We are catching a linker error:

```
2>cryptlib.lib(x64dll.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 * CryptoPP::rdtable::Te" (?Te@rdtable@CryptoPP@@3PA_KA)
2>x64\Output\Debug\cryptest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The missing symbol is located in ***`rijndael.cpp`***, and its its used in ***`x64dll.asm`*** like so:

```
include ksamd64.inc
EXTERNDEF ?Te@rdtable@CryptoPP@@3PA_KA:FAR
EXTERNDEF ?g_cacheLineSize@CryptoPP@@3IA:FAR
EXTERNDEF ?SHA256_K@CryptoPP@@3QBIB:FAR
...
```

The source files are compiled with ***`/GL`***, so we can't use ***`dumpbin /symbols`*** on ***`rijndael.obj`*** to inspect the object files to see what's going on with this configuration. Also see Dumpbin's [/SYMBOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx) documentation and [Why is DumpBin telling me there are no COMDATs in my binaries...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3360498).

Microsoft's documentation tells us what we can't use, but it fails to tell us what we should use in this situation.

How do we locate and display symbols in object files when compiling with ***`/GL`***?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `LINK /LIB /LTCG /OUT:output.lib rijndael.obj` it should produce a static library with actual compiled code. You can then run `dumpbin /ALL output.lib` to see the symbols. `dumpbin /SYMBOLS output.lib` does *not* work for me.

You may need to adjust the `LINK` line to include additional flags that are usually passed when you link. E.g., `/LIBPATH` entries and the like.